# Basic definition of continuity

Tags: continuity, axiom-of-choice

Ltf(c+h) = f(c)(h goes to 0) if and only if Ltf(x) = f(c)(x goes to c).

I am able to prove this fact using sequential criterion of continuity. But sequential criterion is dependent on Axiom of countable choice.

Is above result also dependent on axiom of countable choice.
I think no because different books use both definition equivalently.

Comment: Use the $\varepsilon$-$\delta$ criterion.

Comment: Is there a reason that you are dumping questions "can this be done without choice" without searching first, or without trying to write a proof yourself?